# Object property binding library

Tags: java, javafx, properties

Is there a separate library which does exactly the same as the javafx Propery (javafx.beans.property)?
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/Property.html

Background:
I want to use property binding in my application layer. But since javafx is an UI framework, I don´t want to use the javafx.beans.property class.
I simply want to avoid dependencies from my application logic to UI related code.

Comment: Note there is nothing inherently UI-related about the `javafx.beans.property` classes: they don't rely on the FX toolkit running (or even being present). So you could make the case that using them is simply relying on a library in the same sense as any other property binding framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Eclipse's core databinding framework. It has support for POJOs, Beans and other data structures like EMF models.
Here is a link to JFace databinding, but the core databinding can be used without JFace (UI).

https://wiki.eclipse.org/JFace_Data_Binding

Comment: I cannot see any reason to use this one over JavaFX properties, as this is also mainly used to bind models to the UI (and JavaFX is shipped with the JDK).

Comment: I have already used Eclipse's core databinding framework without any UI toolkits. It is the UI (SWT/Jface) which uses the core databinding framework...

Comment: It's clear that you don't have to build a full RCP application to use the databinding framework. I am just saying that you can do the same with JavaFX - the UI toolkit will be there nevertheless because it is part of JDK8 and will part of JDK9 also. I did not want to be offensive - your answer totally fits the question -, it is just my personal opinion and a fact in parenthesis:). I used both for backends, and I know that both work.

Comment: AFAIK, it depends on the JRE in use wether javafx packages are available or not, for example, the OpenJDK does not have it included by default.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right - OpenJDK does not include it indeed :)